# Scala: Write log to file with log4j

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jar, log4j

I am trying to build a scala based jar file in eclipse that uses log4j to make logs. It prints out perfectly in the console but when I try to use log4j.properties file to make it write to a log file, nothing happens.

The project structure is as follows

[image: Maven project with scala nature]

loggerTest.scala

```
package scala.n*****.n****

import org.apache.log4j.Logger

object loggerTest extends LogHelper {
  def main(args : Array[String]){
    log.info("This is info");
    log.error("This is error");
    log.warn("This is warn");
  }
}

trait LogHelper {
  lazy val log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass.getName)
}
```

log4j.properties

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/home/abc/test/abc.log
log4j.appender.file.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=2kB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>loggerTest</groupId>
<artifactId>loggerTest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>loggerTest</name>
<description>loggerTest</description>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>scala-tools.org</id>
    <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
    <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
  </repository>
  <repository>
    <id>maven-hadoop</id>
    <name>Hadoop Releases</name>
    <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/</url>
  </repository>
  <repository>
    <id>cloudera-repos</id>
    <name>Cloudera Repos</name>
    <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <id>scala-tools.org</id>
    <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
    <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- mixed scala/java compile -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-scala-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.15.2,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute></execute>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<dependencies>
 <dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>


<artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
          <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
          <version>2.10.4</version>
        </dependency> 
      </dependencies>

    </project>
```

When I run it as a maven build, it generates a jar file in "target" folder.

I copy the jar to /home/abc/test

I run that jar in spark shell with command

```
   $ spark-submit --class scala.n*****.n*****.loggerTest loggerTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The console come out alright but it should write to a file in /home/abc/log which it does not.

Could someone please help?

Comment: can you just  try with this ? log4j.rootLogger=WARN, file

Comment: I think Spark has its own default log4j properties which override yours since you're running this via `spark-submit`. Try running your code independently (e.g. `java -jar loggerTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` or `scala loggerTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`) to see your config works, and then read this about logging with Spark-submit: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#configuring-logging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello while you are deploying you application you should define log4j file for executor and driver as follows

```
spark-submit --class MAIN_CLASS --driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:PATH_OF_LOG4J" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:PATH_OF_LOG4J" --master MASTER_IP:PORT JAR_PATH
```

For more details and step by step solution you can check this link https://blog.knoldus.com/2016/02/23/logging-spark-application-on-standalone-cluster/

Comment: The line worked but only if I put the properties file in the same directory as the jar. But I can't seem to give the path of the props file that is in src/main/resources. Could you help me with that?

Comment: you deploy your application with client mode soo you should always put java extra options by arguments cant set in your spark conf because till that jvm is started and if you are passing it by arguments you cant access log4j in your jar

Comment: you can put it somewhere and give path of that is not ok?