# how to submit custom log4j.xml file using spark-submit on multi-node cluster using HDFS with spark standalone cluster manager

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, hdfs, apache-spark-standalone

I am submitting java jar using spark-submit to spark standalone cluster manager. But I am not able to provide custom log4j.xml file to it.
If i used --files option then i need to copy that log4j file to all machines at that same position or if I give it using hdfs:// path then it is not taking that file as log4j and switch to default log4j file.

I also used -Dlog4j.configuration with both local and hdfs path but same issue is happening as using --files.

Please help me if someone know the solution

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Spark does not support writing logs in HDFS using log4j rather you can write the logs local in your unix box.

The porperties for specifying log4j in spark-submit command are:

```
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration= Location of your log4j.properties file"

--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration= location of your log4j.properties file"
```

You have to create a custom log4j.properties file not log4j.xml in your local unix box.

If you want to create custom logs in HDFS you can create a interface in java or trait in scala to specify the loging levels and write the log to HDFS
for more reference you can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058460/scala-write-log-to-file-with-log4j).

Comment: I am writing log into unix box, i am just reading the log4j file from HDFS location. As using log4j.configuration it search the file from local fs, so i need to copy the saem file to all my worker nodes.
So I am searching a way to submit log4j file from HDFS or from client machine, so that it will not needed to copy on all nodes

Comment: no need of copying the log4j file to all the nodes. The node from which you submit jobs it must be fixed so the file should be in that node only and whenever you submit it a job spark loads the external jars r files that you specify in spark-submit into the cluster for running in distributed mode.

Comment: yes I am using the fixed node, but when i gave the path of log4j file, it will search that path on driver node which was different from the submitted node due to which I got below error:

log4j:ERROR Could not parse url [file:/data/log4j.xml].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/log4j.xml (No such file or directory)

Comment: Specify the log4j.properties file through the above parameters in my answer not through --files parameter. can you please show me your spark-submit command?

Comment: I am using -Dlog4j.configuration variable. The spark-submit command is as follow:
spark-submit --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///data/log4j.xml"  --deploy-mode cluster --master $SPARK_MASTER  --class com.main hdfs://xyz.jar

Comment: this should be the command `spark-submit --class xyz --master "yarn" --deploy-mode "client" 
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=../conf/spark-log4j.properties" 
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=../conf/spark-log4j.properties" 
../lib/xyz.jar`

Comment: I need to used spark-standalone cluster manager. The above command is already working for yarn cluster manager using --files option for log4j.xml file

Comment: yes this command is for client mode or standalone mode. Basically in whichever node you keep your jar the properties file should also be there no need of keeping in all nodes.

Comment: yes it will work if i used client mode but my job is long running job which need to be run in cluster mode so that I can monitor it using spark UI and all the resource handling will be taken care by spark itself. So client mode did not solve my issue.